# Implementing Google maps for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, dictionary

I have given the alternative for apple maps which is called as Google maps. This question and answer has solution for how to create google map and create a marker on map with description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First finish the steps listed in this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start
2. Code for creating map.

   ```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude
                                               longitude:coordinate.longitude 
                                                            zoom:15];
   mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120) camera:camera];
   [mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
   mapView.delegate = self;
   mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
   [self.view addSubview:mapView];

   //getlocation method
   -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
   CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

   return coordinate;
   }
   ```
3. Creating marker for current location on map.

   ```
    [[GMSGeocoder geocoder]         reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
    NSLog( @"Error is %@", error) ;
    NSLog( @"%@" , response.firstResult.addressLine1 ) ;
    NSLog( @"%@" , response.firstResult.addressLine2 ) ;
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = coordinate;
    marker.title = response.firstResult.addressLine1;
    marker.snippet = response.firstResult.addressLine2;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    NSArray* parts = [response.firstResult.addressLine2 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];
    locValueLabel.text = [parts objectAtIndex:0];

    marker.map = mapView;
    } ] ;
   ```